# listbox keyborad opreation in gwt

Tags: gwt, gxt

how to get focus on listbox items through keyboard and selected the item in  textbox by pressing enter

Answer (score 0):

You can give a `ListBox` focus by calling `setFocus(true)` on it.  The keyboard/enter behavior you mention is provided automatically.